# Javascript code for calling CSS animation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have a simple html page with div and form elements, that are simply animated after the page is loaded.

Here is HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/global.css">        
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/index.css">
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wholepage">
        <div id="loginformdiv">
        </div>
        <form id="loginform">
            <p id="loginformh">Login</p>
            <input type="text" id="loginformusr" placeholder="Uživatelské jméno">
            <input type="password" id="loginformpw" placeholder="Heslo">
            <input type="button" value="›" id="loginformsubmit" onclick="loginformcheck()">
            </p><p id="loginformalert"></p>     
        </form>
    </div>
</html>
```

I've created 4 animations for div and form. First two are supposed to load after the index.html is loaded. These two are working normally. But the last two animations should load after user hits button and my js code checks if the form is filled correctly. After end of these animation it should load to afterlogin.html page.

Here is part of my CSS code:

```
@keyframes afterstartdiv {
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 0.5;}
}

@keyframes afterstartform {
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes afterlogindiv {
from {opacity: 0.5;}
to {opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes afterloginform {
from {opacity: 1;}
to {opacity: 0;}
}
```

Here is my whole js code:

```
function loginformcheck() {
var username = document.getElementById("loginformusr").value;
var password = document.getElementById("loginformpw").value;


if (username.length == 0 && password.length == 0)
{
    document.getElementById("loginformalert").innerHTML = "Vyplňte přihlašovací údaje!";
}
else if (username.length == 0)
{
    document.getElementById("loginformalert").innerHTML = "Vyplňte přihlašovací jméno!";
}
else if (password.length == 0)
{
    document.getElementById("loginformalert").innerHTML = "Vyplňte heslo!";
}
else if (!username.match(/^\w+$/) || !password.match(/^\w+$/)) 
{
    document.getElementById("loginformalert").innerHTML = "Uživatelské jméno nebo heslo je nesprávné!";
}
else if (username.match(/^\w+$/) && password.match(/^\w+$/))
{
    login();
}
}

function login() {
var username = document.getElementById("loginformusr").value;
var password = document.getElementById("loginformpw").value;
var alert = "Uživatelské jméno nebo heslo je nesprávné!";

if (username.match("jakub") && password.match("poiuz"))
{
    function afterloginanimation(timer) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            if (timer == -1) {
                window.location.href = "afterlogin.html";
            }
        }, 1500);   
    }
    document.getElementById("loginformdiv").style.AnimationName = "afterlogindiv";
    document.getElementById("loginformdiv").style.AnimationDuration = "1.5s";
    document.getElementById("loginform").style.AnimationName = "afterloginform";
    document.getElementById("loginform").style.AnimationDuration = "1.5s";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("loginformalert").innerHTML = alert;
}
```

}

Comment: Where is your JS code? Is it being called in the head? Or are you waiting for document ready?

Comment: Whole js code is located in external file "scripts.js". There is no problem with location. The function, that checks correct fill of form is working well.

Comment: Hi, just a thought: instead of setting inline animation properties, can you try defining a class with all of them and add it to the target elements?

ex:
#loginformdiv.animating {
    animation: afterlogindiv 1.5s;
}

#loginform.animating {
    animation: afterloginform 1.5s;
}

Comment: Sory I haven't done this yet, so I don't understand you a bit :D. Where should I put these lines from your example?

Comment: I've edited my question and added whole js code. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks correct on that to me, have you tried just setting the timeout a little longer? Also when you say it doesnt work do you get a console error? If not can you console log inside the timeout function to verify that it is actually ever firing?

Comment: Here is console error: SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'AnimationName' of undefined or null reference

Comment: This is straight up a curiosity but an you try including this is your <head> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8;FF=3;OtherUA=4" />

Comment: Problem is still same after adding your meta tag. Actually, it does weird things in IE 11. I forgot to tell, that I'm mainly using Microsoft Edge.

Comment: I've edited my question and added whole js code. Hope it helps.